# How to do a join on two tables with Linq using this EDMX diagram?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

I am kind of stuck at writing the Linq join query to select every student along with every subject he/she is studying (actually I'm not sure if it even is a join because of the `StudentsSubjects` table). The `SubjectId` and `StudentId` in the `StudentsSubject` table are the foreign keys, and the third `Id` column in it is the primary key.

This is the edmx below. I think I can do that in SQL but I haven't been able to translate it to Linq.

Additionally, if someone could please point out if this database model (oversimplified though it is) is "correct" i.e. the many to many relationship between students and subjects is done right (i.e. each student may have multiple subjects, and vice versa)

Thank you :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from student in ctx.Student
select new
{
    Student = student,
    Subjects = from studsub in student.StudentsSubjects
               select studsub.Subject
};
```

The relationships look fine.